# If we randomly pick a n-degree polynomial, is the probability of getting complex roots higher than the probability of getting all real roots?

Tags: probability, polynomials, roots

Intuitively, I feel the probability of getting all roots of a polynomial to be real to be less. But is there a proof for this statement?

Comment: what is your probability distribution over the set of all $n$ degree polynomials?

Comment: the coefficients are real and uniformly distributed.

Comment: Almost are are complex. See my little-thinking-involved answer below.

Comment: You can't have uniformly distributed real coefficients.  Do you perhaps mean the coefficients are in the unit cube?

Comment: Yes, that is what I had meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Google search for
"distribution of number of real roots in a polynomial"
came up with this
as the first hit:

https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/sjmiller/public_html/ntprob12/handouts/polyzeros/Fairley_NumbRealRootsRandPolySmallDeg.pdf

Here is the title and abstract:

THE NUMBER OF REAL ROOTS OF RANDOM
POLYNOMIALS OF SMALL DEGREE*

By WILLIAM B. PAIRLEY
Kennedy School of Government, Harvard University

SUMMARY. Random polynomials with random coefficients have been studied by a
number of authors, including Kac (1943, 1949), who showed that the average number of real roots
of polynomials of degree n is asymptotically $(2/\pi) \log n$. The present paper investigates the average number of real roots for polynomials of small degree and coefficients that are 1 or - 1 with equal
probability. Log-like behavior of the average for small n is shown by finding exact distributions
of the numbers of real roots for n between 1 and 10 and by sampling the large but finite populations
for n between 10 and 50.

(end)

Since the number of real roots
of a polynomial of degree $n$
is about $(2/\pi) \log n$,
the vast majority of roots
are complex.

Here are the references:

Bloch, A. and Polya, G. (1932) : On the roots of certain algebraic equations. Proc. London
Math. Soc, II, 33, 102-114.

Erdos, P. and Offord, A. (1956) : On the number of real roots of a random algebraic equation.
Proc. London Math. Soc, 6, 139-160.

Ibragimov, I. and Maslova, N. (1971) : On the expected number of real zeros of random
polynomials I. Coefficients with zero means. Theory of Probability and its Applications,
XVI, No. 2.

Kac, M. (1943) : On the average number of real roots of a random algebraic equation. Bulletin
American Math. Soc, 49, 314-320.

-(1949) : On the average number of real roots of a random algebraic equation (II). Proc.
London Math. Soc, 50, 390-408.

Lilley, F. (1967) : Zeros of a Polynomial. General electric information series, No. 65SD351.

Littlewood, J. and Offord, A. (1939) : On the number of real roots of a random algebraic
equation II. Proc Cambridge Phil. Soc, 35, 133-148.

Stevens, D. (1965) : The average number of real zeros of a random polynomial, doctoral dissertation, New York University, Department of Mathematics.